# Extract part of image by its image map coordinates and display it inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an image which is being displayed by a canvas and I have coordinates like this

```
428,361,432,374,475,399,470,472,420,
494,400,486,328,461,183,409,176,386,
178,356,182,345,270,309,192,288,072,
257,069,228,069,219,077,212,112,205,
133,207,185,201,213,203,277,215,291,
220,298,222,323,225,388,235,418,244,
412,269,393,312,387,332,388,349,407,
356,414,360
```

which are in an `<area>` tag format.

What I want to do is to extract that area from my image and display it (that extracted area) inside another canvas.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I have coordinates like this? Do you have a 66 dimensional coordinate system? x,y,z...¸,¹,º? Sorry, but that is really unclear; Do your coordinates look more like: (428,361),(432,374)...?

Comment: @minseong I don't know the name of that kind of coordinate ,Thats why I have place an example But I make those coordinates from x and y of user's clicks.

Comment: @minseong It is a set of `<area>` tag coordinates for a `<map>` tag

Comment: @charlietfl that's right.

Comment: So all of those are for one area tag? What's its shape? Poly?

Comment: @minseong yes,It's just for one area and it's poly.

Comment: @omid So is your image being displayed *by* the first canvas, or by an `<img>` tag?

Comment: @minseong it's displaying by the first canvas.

Comment: How have you specified those coordinates? Can you post the appropriate HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your area points are actually point-pairs of a polygon. That polygon is the desired area of the source image.

Here's how to extract the area mapped pixels from the source image:

- Calculate the bounding box of the area coordinates: minX,minY & maxX,maxY
- Resize the destination canvas to the size of the bounding box:

  ```
  width=maxX-minX, height=maxY-minY
  ```
- Create a clipping path on the destination. The clipping path is the original area moved to the top-left of the destination canvas.

  ```
  // draw the clipping path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pointpairs[0]-minX,pointpairs[1]-minY);
  for(var i=2;i<pointpairs.length;i+=2){
      var x=pointpairs[i];
      var y=pointpairs[i+1];
      ctx.lineTo(x-minX,y-minY);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();
  ```
- Draw the image onto the destination canvas, but offset by minY & minY

  ```
  ctx.drawImage(img,-minX,-minY);
  ```

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var srcCanvas=document.getElementById("source");
var sctx=srcCanvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var pointpairs=[
  428,361,432,374,475,399,470,472,420,
  494,400,486,328,461,183,409,176,386,
  178,356,182,345,270,309,192,288,072,
  257,069,228,069,219,077,212,112,205,
  133,207,185,201,213,203,277,215,291,
  220,298,222,323,225,388,235,418,244,
  412,269,393,312,387,332,388,349,407,
  356,414,360];
var minX=1000000;
var minY=minX;
var maxX=-1000000;
var maxY=maxX;

for(var i=0;i<pointpairs.length;i+=2){
  var x=pointpairs[i];
  var y=pointpairs[i+1];
  if(x<minX){minX=x;}
  if(y<minY){minY=y;}
  if(x>maxX){maxX=x;}
  if(y>maxY){maxY=y;}
}

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/transportation.jpg';
function start(){

  srcCanvas.width=img.width;
  srcCanvas.height=img.height;

  sctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  // draw the source image
  // and also stroke the text area
  sctx.lineWidth=2;
  sctx.strokeStyle='blue';
  sctx.beginPath();
  sctx.moveTo(pointpairs[0],pointpairs[1]);
  for(var i=2;i<pointpairs.length;i+=2){
    var x=pointpairs[i];
    var y=pointpairs[i+1];
    sctx.lineTo(x,y);
  }
  sctx.closePath();
  sctx.stroke();

  // resize the canvas to the <area> bounding box size
  canvas.width=maxX-minX;
  canvas.height=maxY-minY;

  // draw the clipping path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pointpairs[0]-minX,pointpairs[1]-minY);
  for(var i=2;i<pointpairs.length;i+=2){
    var x=pointpairs[i];
    var y=pointpairs[i+1];
    ctx.lineTo(x-minX,y-minY);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();

  ctx.drawImage(img,-minX,-minY);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color:black; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="source" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: There is a problem with this.Let's say ,after drawing the image in the first canvas ,we want to display another picture on half top of the original picture the another picture on the half bottom But after extracting that part ,it does take picture of the first picture and not include two other pictures that we have drawn after that .What should I do about that?

Comment: Just clear the canvas and redraw the full/partial images in your desired order. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have used to make those coordinates

```
function clipIt(){
  // calculate the size of the user's clipping area
  if(points=="")
   bootbox.alert("Not selected", function() {

    });
  else{
  var minX=10000;
  var minY=10000;
  var maxX=-10000;
  var maxY=-10000;
  for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    var p=points[i];
    if(p.x<minX){minX=p.x;}
    if(p.y<minY){minY=p.y;}
    if(p.x>maxX){maxX=p.x;}
    if(p.y>maxY){maxY=p.y;}
  }
  var width=maxX-minX;
  var height=maxY-minY;

  // clip the image into the user's clipping area
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    var p=points[i];
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.restore();

  // create a new canvas 
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  var cx=c.getContext('2d');

  // resize the new canvas to the size of the clipping area
  c.width=width;
  c.height=height;

  // draw the clipped image from the main canvas to the new canvas
  cx.drawImage(canvas, minX,minY,width,height, 0,0,width,height);

  // create a new Image() from the new canvas
  var clippedImage=new Image();
  //clippedImage.name="img"+ nameimageis 
  clippedImage.id="img"+ nameimageis
  clippedImage.onload=function(){
    // append the new image to the page

    //document.body.appendChild(clippedImage );
    new_parts=new_parts+1;
    $("#contain").append(clippedImage)
    $("#img"+nameimageis ).wrap( "<div class='ins' id='in_"+nameimageis+"'></div>" );
    $("#in_"+nameimageis ).append("<input type='hidden' id='new_"+nameimageis+"' value='new'/><div class='inner' id='inner_"+nameimageis+"' onclick='removeit("+nameimageis+")'></div>");

    nameimageis++; 
  }
  clippedImage.src=c.toDataURL();


  // clear the previous points 
  points.length=0;

  // redraw the image on the main canvas for further clipping
  drawImage(1);

}
}
```

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, not an answer. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @minseong ops.Sorry,That's the code which clipit if that's what you meant.

Comment: @minseong I guess we need to fill points array by those coordinates and Call the function.But How?